# How to solve this issue with php ML?

Tags: php, composer-php

`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares::predict(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\490\testing.php on line 18 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\490\vendor\php-ai\php-ml\src\Helper\Predictable.php:12`

```
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\490\testing.php(18): Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares->predict()
#1 {main} 
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\490\vendor\php-ai\php-ml\src\Helper\Predictable.php on line 12
```

I installed composer and php ML and this was my code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Loading the data 

$data = new \Phpml\Dataset\CsvDataset(filepath: "./data/insurance.csv", features: 1, headingRow:          true);

// preprocessing the data
$dataset = new \Phpml\CrossValidation\RandomSplit($data, testSize: 0.2, seed: 156);
//$dataset->getTrainSamples();
//$dataset->getTrainLabels();
//$dataset->getTestSamples();
//$dataset->getTestLabels();
// Training
$regression = new \Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares();
$regression->train($dataset->getTrainSamples(),$dataset->getTrainLabels());

$regression->predict();
// Evaluating machihne learning models
$score = \Phpml\Metric\Regression::r2Score($dataset->getTestLabels(),$predict);
echo "r2score is : " . $score;
// Making predictions with training models
```

Any help would be appreciated

I tried to see if the issue was with my file path. I'm not 100% sure with the syntax but I still receive this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Such error messages require reading. That is letter by letter, especially if this all new or surprising (the error). Again and again until you have understood every single words meaning. Then map it on your code. `$regression->predict();` is causing the error. The rest is debugging you need to do. It looks like you're calling this function wrong. Only guess the first three minutes while debugging. If that leads to no correct results, start to go through step by step, double check everything against the documentation and the source code. A step debugger can help, e.g. Xdebug.

Comment: Is there something about the error message "Too few arguments to function Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares::predict(), 0 passed [...] exactly 1 expected" that is unclear?

Comment: @ArshadoThe `$regression->predict()` method is expecting you to pass an array. The docs are available at https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and there's a sample to help you get started right near the top.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It was a good bonk to the head and I have no clue how I missed that. I modified the predict() to $predict = $regression->predict($dataset->getTestSamples()); and it worked successfully. Thank you!

Comment: @Arshado if you are new to coding, you have to learn the very basic and first step to start coding i.e., read, read, read. Read everything before you start something. Read docs, Read errors, Read example codes. [Try to read this too.](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/regression/least-squares/#predict)

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, why did you tag this question with [tag:composer-php]?

Comment: Thank you for the document. And @NicoHaase I installed php ML with composer so I just wanted to include a related tag. $predict = $regression->predict($dataset->getTestSamples()); was my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LeastSquares Linear Regression, to predict sample target value use predict method with sample to check (as array).

For example, if the value you want to check is 123, then

```
$regression->predict([123]);
```

which may return something like 4.01 (just as an example)

In your code, you have just used `$regression->predict();`, which obviously is missing the parameter.